# A continuity argument for a dispersive $gKdV$ estimate

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm learning about the gKdV equation, following Schlag & Muscalu vol II. We're looking at
$$\begin{cases} u_t + u_{xxx} + F(u)_x = 0 \\ u_0 = g\end{cases}$$
where $F(u) = u^5$ (for example). The goal is to prove a dispersive estimate $$\sup_t \langle t\rangle^{1/3} \|u(t)\|_\infty <\infty.$$

The step I'm wondering about is this: if $$\|g\| \equiv \|g\|_1 + \|g\|_{H^1}$$ is sufficiently small, then $$\|u(t)\|_2 + \|u_x(t)\|_2 \lesssim \|g\|_{H^1}.$$

Clearly we just need to show the derivative bounded, by the conservation of $L^2$ norm.

Eventually, we get this result:
$$\|\partial_x u(t)\|_2^2 \le \epsilon(1 + \|\partial_x u(t)\|_2^4)$$ for some $\epsilon >0$ small
and for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \ x^2 \le \epsilon (1+ x^4)\} = I_1 \cup I_2 \cup I_3$, where $I_1 = [-r,r], I_2 = [\rho, \infty)$ and $I_3 = (-\infty, - \rho]$ for some $0< r << \rho$, which is easy to see. For $\epsilon>0$ small enough, $\rho > 2r$.

By Kato's theorem $\partial_x u: \mathbb{R} \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is weakly continuous, and the norm $\|\cdot \|_2$ is always weakly lower semicontinuous. Also by assumption we know $\|\partial_x u(0) \|_2 \in I_1$ if we take $\|g\|$ small enough.

This is supposed to ensure that, in fact, $\|\partial_x u(t)\|_2 \in I_1$ for all time $t$, since the image is supposed to lie in the connected component containing $\|\partial_x u(0)\|_2$, which is $I_1$. This would give the desired goal, which is that $\|\partial_x u\|_2$ is $O(1)$ (and hence $O(\epsilon)$).

However, I don't know how to get the required connectedness. It is true that $\partial_x u(\mathbb{R})$ is weakly connected in $H^1$. We also know that $\|\partial_x u\|_2(\mathbb{R}) \subset I_1 \cup I_2$. But then lower semi-continuity of the norm doesn't seem to be enough to ensure that $\|\partial_x u\|_2(\mathbb{R})$ is connected. In the paper by [Christ and Weinstein](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82466311.pdf) (hyperlinked), page 100, they use an identical argument but specifically make note of the fact that the norm is varying continuously.

So, how can we make do with $\partial_x u: \mathbb{R} \to L^2 $ being only weakly continuous? Any bootstrapping/continuity argument I can come up with ultimately needs that the norm can't jump, which I don't know if we have.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with your feeling that the continuity of the norm of $\|\partial_x u\|_2$ looks necessary to conclude. Having weak continuity, that would imply strong continuity, too.